# ./gradlew assembleRegularRelease only work with sudo

Tags: react-native, macos, sudo, gradlew

When I try run the command ./gradlew assembleRegularRelease inside android directory in my React Native project, I receive an error, but when try run using sudo, it's work. Someone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give r-w Read Write permission to the folder and you can achieve this by below steps :

For MacOS :

Right Click the folder >> Get Info >> Press Lock button below. >> Enter your password  >> now Click on left bottom round three dot icon >> then click Apply to all enclosed Item >>  Done .

For Windows refer this :

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373